# Editing Model Attributes using has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations, has-many-through

I've sucessfully created a `has_many through` join with two of my models. To summarize, each Artist can belong to a number of groups and vice versa:

```
# artist.rb
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships

# membership.rb
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :group

# group.rb
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :artists, through: :memberships
```

What I'd like to do is setup a `status` attribute that would be a boolean and indicate whether an artist belongs to that group anymore. So for instance if an artist left the group he/she would be identified as a **Past Member** boolean named `status` (true = current_member, false = past_member).

I'm not sure of a few things. The first is deciding on which model to assign this attribute to. Is it all three? Is it 2/3 or 1/3?

The second question I had was creating a way that would allow me to change the membership status of an artist in either the edit view of the artists or the group(s) they belong to. What I'm hoping to do is that if one is changed from either view, this change is reflected upon both models.

The artist and group show views would probably mirror each other so for the sake of brevity I'll just list the artist's show view:

**Artist Show View**

The only part I'm having trouble with is trying to list the past groups. Should I setup a scope or a method for this particular scenario?

```
<h3>Member of:</h3>
<hr>
<% @artist.groups.each do |group| %>
    <%= artist.group.name %>
    <% if artist.group.status == false %>
        <h3>Past Member of: %></h3>
        <hr>
        <!-- <% Scope or Method that filters Past Groups %> -->
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Artist Edit View**

For the edit view the one thing I can't seem to figure out is nesting each group of the artist. My syntax is probably way off but just to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
<%= form_for @artist do |f| %>
  <h3>Memberships</h3>
  <% @artist.groups.each do |group| %>
    <%= f.group.radio_button :status, true %>
    <%= f.group.label :status, 'Current Member', value: true %>
    <%= f.group.radio_button :status, false %>
    <%= f.group.label :status, 'Past Member', value: false %>
  <% end %>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Group Edit View**

I'm assuming that this would look almost exactly like the artist edit view but reversed to an extent:

```
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>
  <h3>Memberships</h3>
  <% @group.artists.each do |artist| %>
    <div>
      <%= f.artist.radio_button :status, true %>
      <%= f.artist.label :status, 'Current Member', value: true %>
      <%= f.artist.radio_button :status, false %>
      <%= f.artist.label :status, 'Past Member', value: false %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If there's any controller logic needed I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would add this to `Membership` as this is the true indicator of the relationship

Since you are looking at a single group or artist it would be an instance method instead of a scope. something like:

```
class Group
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :artists, through: :memberships
  def past_artists
    artists.where(memberships:{status: false})
  end
end
#might be User not sure based on your code and your question
class Artist
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
  def past_groups
    groups.where(memberships:{status: false})
  end
end
```

Then your group view should probably be something like

```
<% @group.memberships.each do |membership| %>
   <%= render '/memberships/membership_edit_form', membership: membership, obj: @group %>
<% end %>
```

and create a partial `/memberships/_membership_edit_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for membership do |f| %>
   <h5><%= obj.is_a?(Group) ? membership.artist : membership.group %></h5>
   <%= f.label :status, "Current Member?" %>
   <%= f.check_box :status %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Just to note the submit button will only update 1 membership relationship at a time.

**To update multiple at once you should be able to do this**

```
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :memberships do |builder| %>
     <%= render '/memberships/membership_fields', f: builder, obj: @group %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then create a partial in `/memberships/_membership_fields.html.erb` like

```
<h5><%= obj.is_a?(Group) ? f.object.artist : f.object.group %></h5>
<%= f.label :status, "Current Member?" %>
<%= f.check_box :status %>
```

This should allow you to pass them all through params as something like `[:group][:memberships]` but note I believe to properly update these you will have to iterate the collection.

Comment: After creating a migration for my `membership` model I added the two methods mentioned in your answer but when I tried either of the two in the rails console I got `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'artists'`

Comment: @CarlEdwards I fixed `Artist` it should have said `groups` but with your associations `Group` should have an `artists` method because you have `has_many :artists, through: :memberships`.

Comment: Let me make sure I'm doing this right. In my rails console I first did `a = Artist.first`. Then did g = a.groups.first. I finally did `g.status` and I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'status' for #<Group:0x007f91e9a829d8>`

Comment: Also ran into this error when I inserted the view code for artists: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)`

Comment: @CarlEdwards `status` should be part of `Membership` so you could do `a = Artist.first` then run something like `a.memberships.each {|m| puts "Group: #{m.group.name} Status: #{m.status}` and it will output something like "Group: Group Name Status: false". The artist and the group individually have no status they only have a status as an association.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick in console. Any idea how to fix the view code?

Comment: @CarlEdwards I updated my post a bit I think it had to do with `radio_button` and `label` syntax. I don't use `form_for` very much. I also realized a flaw in my design so I have changed the the base view and the partial. You can now use the same partial for the artist and group views

Comment: I'll try this in a minute. What confuses me is why it threw an error when it was formatted as a radio button. Aren't the checkbox and radio button essentially the same in this case since we're dealing with a Boolean?

Comment: @CarlEdwards The method signatures are slightly different and you could do radio buttons for yes/no but for the ease of simplicity at this point a single check box indicates both. radio_button expects a method and a value. checkbox is a true boolean indicator on only expects a method.

Comment: This seems to work but would you be able to provide a way to update the statuses of multiple models in the edit form partial (I originally intended to have it work that way in my question)? I'd be more than happy to provide a bonus point in addition to marking the answer as correct.

Comment: @CarlEdwards updated my answer although I think at this point the rest is in your hands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63590/discussion-between-carl-edwards-and-engineersmnky).

Comment: With the updated code, the records aren't being saved at all now